# Javascript extra tag when performing appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to achieve the following output:

```
  <ul class="deck">
      <li class="card">
          <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="card">
          <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
      </li>

         ...
   </ul>
```

But instead, when I run my code, I am getting:

```
  <ul class="deck">

      <li>
          <li class="card">
              <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
          </li>
      <li>
          <li class="card">
              <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
          </li>
      </li>
         ...
   </ul>
```

So as you can see I am getting an extra enclosing `<li>` tag.  I have tried several approaches, to no avail.  The JS generating this html is:

```
const gameDeck = document.querySelector(".deck");
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (i = 0; i < cardArray.length; i++) {
    const newElement = document.createElement('LI');
    newElement.innerHTML = "<li class=\"card\"><i 
    class="+cardArray[i]+"></i></li>"

    fragment.appendChild(newElement);
}

gameDeck.appendChild(fragment);
```

Comment: please provide cardArray array or jsfiddle

Comment: You create an `li` element and then write an `<li>` tag to its inner HTML, the result is of course an `li` element within your first `li` element

Comment: @MikaelLennholm Using terms like "of course" is somewhat condescending, considering what's obvious to _you_ might not be obvious to others, especially if they're new 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are inserting an `li` into newElement, which is already an `li`. Try this instead:

```
const gameDeck = document.querySelector(".deck");
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (i = 0; i < cardArray.length; i++) {
    const newElement = document.createElement('LI');
    newElement.className = 'card';
    newElement.innerHTML = "<i class="+cardArray[i]+"></i>"
    fragment.appendChild(newElement);
}

gameDeck.appendChild(fragment);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const newElement = document.createElement('LI');
```

This creates an `<li></li>`.

The innerHTML property sets the content *inside* of the element
So if you put `<li>` *inside* the `<li>`, you'll end up with `<li><li></li></li>`

Instead, set the innerHTML to what you actually want to be inside the `<li>`, excluding the `<li>` that's already there. Template string used here for readability.

```
newElement.innerHTML = `<i class=${cardArray[i]}></i>`
```

Then, attach the class to the li as well. Two different ways of doing so. I prefer the second, especially if you want to add a bunch of classes later.

```
newElement.className = 'card'
newElement.classList.add('card')
```

However, you can circumvent *all* of the above using `outerHTML` instead, which does what I believe you expected `innerHTML` to do.

```
const newElement = document.createElement('LI');
newElement.outerHTML = "<li class=\"card\"><i class="+cardArray[i]+"></i></li>"
```

[See this page on MDN for more details on outerHTML.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a LI element, it has already the `<li>` and `</li>` tags. Don't add them again.

```
const gameDeck = document.querySelector(".deck");
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (i = 0; i < cardArray.length; i++) {
    const newElement = document.createElement('LI');
    newElement.setAttribute('class', 'card');
    newElement.innerHTML = "<i class="+cardArray[i]+"></i>"

    fragment.appendChild(newElement);
}

gameDeck.appendChild(fragment);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an LI element and then putting an `<li>` element into it. Just do this:

```
const gameDeck = document.querySelector(".deck");
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

  for (i = 0; i < cardArray.length; i++) {
      const newElement = document.createElement('LI');
      newElement.innerHTML = "<i class="+cardArray[i]+"></i>"

      fragment.appendChild(newElement);
  }

  gameDeck.appendChild(fragment);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an li and then adding the inner html of "li" -- try removing the li inside of the innerHTML

```
const gameDeck = document.querySelector(".deck");
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (i = 0; i < cardArray.length; i++) {
    const newElement = document.createElement("li");
    newElement.className = "card";
    newElement.innerHTML = "<i class="+cardArray[i]+"></i>"

    fragment.appendChild(newElement);
}

gameDeck.appendChild(fragment);
```